# Get nearby div child element with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, find, children, closest

How can I get nearby div's child element with jquery ?
I'm trying to validate() my input element I need to get `class=grand_child_02`, when I'm in `class=input_01`

*HTML:*

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_01">
      <h4 class="grand_child_01_01">
        <a href="#" class="link_01">link_01</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="grand_child_01_02">Some_text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="child_02">
     <div class="grand_child_02_01">
       <input type="text" class="input_01"/>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For clarification of my comments:

I have upvoted both the other answers as correct, but would suggest a slight tweak by only using `siblings()` without a filter.

```
var $target = $(this).closest('.child_02').siblings().find('.grand_child_02');
```

Where `this` is the input element you specified.

If you just use siblings(), it will work with additional added sibling div elements (which may be likely to occur in practical situations). I consider this a little more robust to changes (and insignificantly slower than with using the siblings filter).

e.g. in this example:

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tw3Yc/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**, **[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** and **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**:

```
var grand_child_02 = $(this).closest('.child_02').siblings('.child_01').find('.grand_child_02');
```

with `$(this)` refer to `.input_01` element

Comment: prev() implies a fixed known order... better off using siblings() to remain flexible.

Comment: Ok, I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: +1: That works, but I actually meant just `siblings()` (no filter). Then you only care about the final target filter (might get other siblings later). I realise this is a fiddly detail, but I like to see robust code (less likely to break if layout changes)

Comment: I don't get what you means. It's hard to tell when I don't know how is your layout change and what's exactly you're trying to achieve at this moment

Comment: Have added clarification as a third answer so you can see what I meant. Have up-voted the first two answers (inc yours) as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$(this).closest('.child_02').siblings('div').find('.grand_child_02')
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw3Yc/)**

Comment: +1 for suggesting siblings first in this instance. Shame it was not earliest answer.